# Return the value from a third column identified by a first search value in the first column and a second search value in the second column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I would like to display the value of the third column of a table, which is determined by using two search criteria. The table in which is searched consists of three columns.

- The first column contains the names of the players.
- The second column contains the names of the unit.
- The third column contains the power for the players unit.

Example:

| Player | Unit | power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Magmatrooper | 19020 |
| Bob | Cad Bane | 24250 |
| Bob | TIE Fighter Pilot | 22657 |
| Bob | Grand Master Yoda | 27979 |
| Bob | Shaak Ti | 32988 |

...

| Player | Unit | power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nik | Magmatrooper | 19020 |
| Nik | Cad Bane | 21400 |
| Nik | TIE Fighter Pilot | 17899 |
| Nik | Grand Master Yoda | 23400 |
| Nik | Shaak Ti | 29800 |

My approach: translate an Excel formula to google sheets.

In an Excel spreadsheet, the formula works as shown in Figure 1.
[Formula, that works in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OL01.jpg)

In google sheets i'm stuck.  when the formula is applied it shows an error.
[Formula in google sheets causes #NV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDeel.jpg)

Can anyone tell what the formula should be in google sheets?

Thanks for your support

Best regards

Hermann

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to display the value of the third column I guess you mean the `power` column right? Then, because `power` is numeric, you could search your value using SUMIFS with your criteria...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The third column is a string, it's not numeric. The example only shows a simplified form of the table for a better understanding of my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E3&F1:G1, {A1:A&B1:B, C1:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! @player0
This was exactly what I was looking for.
You made my day 

Best regards
Hermann